# Registration Form with name & password - Binding and securty

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to create some simple form that will be use to registration a user. 
The form include 2 fields 
      1. User name 
      2. Password.

So, i decide to create a class that derivative from ChildWindow. 
I created also a class call 'UserInstance' that have 2 fields 
   name, password.

The question that i have

1. To make the application more secure - i don't want to make the field 'password' to be sting in the class instance ( security reason ) - is there some alternative ?
2. I using the object 'system.windows.controls.PasswordBox' in the silverlight GUI - how can i make the binding between the PasswordBox and the Password object in the class instance ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the binding. You can use it in the same way as for a TextBox.

```
<PasswordBox Password="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="MyPropertyTextBox" />
```

MyProperty is a property of the DataContext of the PasswordBox.
Unfortunately there is nothing like [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in SL. You have to encrypt it by your self. Have a look [here(Cryptographic Services in Silverlight)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265159%28VS.95%29.aspx) or [here(MD5)](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5) or [here(SHA256Managed)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Hope this helps!

BR,

TJ